# what is parameter for select Hub or Persistent Connection?

Tags: c#, signalr, signalr-hub

select Hub or Persistent Connection for server side.
i don not know What is effect the in  client side ?

Comment: dup: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9280484/signalr-why-choose-hub-vs-persistent-connection, the developer has some good points on the differences in his comment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Connectivity wise there is no difference, but if you choose PersistentConnection you will have to create your own client side (and server for that matter) message dispatching logic where as Hubs provide that plumbing for you.