# Is it possible to return a pre-encoded JSON string in a SignalR hub method?

Tags: c#, json, json.net, signalr, signalr-hub

In an MVC project, I have a method on a hub similar to this:

```
public string Foo() { return DoCrazyThingThatReturnsJson(); }
```

Unfortunately SignalR (or something) takes the encoded JSON string and happily encodes it, then returns it, so browser be like LOLWTF. Is there a way to skip this second encoding?

Answer (score 0):

Looking at [this here](https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/blob/2.2.0/src/Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Core/Infrastructure/Connection.cs#L204):

> We assume that any ArraySegment is already JSON serialized

it [seems like something like this may work](https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/blob/master/tests/Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Tests.Common/Connections/PreserializedJsonConnection.cs) (note that I haven't tried it, so no promises):

```
string jsonString = ...; // your serialized data
var jsonBytes = new ArraySegment<byte>(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(jsonString));
Clients.Caller.sendJson(jsonBytes);
```

(The above only works for PersistentConnection because of what constitutes a value - for hubs, the data is wrapped in a container with the RPC info; I'm only leaving this in case using PersistentConnection is an option for you)

Another idea might be creating a container class for a JSON string, then using a custom converter that simply writes the string as-is, then register like this in the Signalr startup code:

```
var serializer = new JsonSerializer();
serializer.Converters.Add(new PreserializedConverter());

GlobalHost.DependencyResolver.Register(typeof(JsonSerializer), () => serializer);
```