# $.hubConnection vs $.connection

Tags: c#, signalr

I want to use signalR with MVC5. I found two or more nice tutorials but I have one question.

What to use:
`$.hubConnection` or `$.connection`

As far I understood, first always connect to hub, second use persisted connection. What is better?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SignalR: Why choose Hub vs. Persistent Connection?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9280484/signalr-why-choose-hub-vs-persistent-connection)

Comment: i thought `$.connection` was given to you by the generated proxy, and `$.hubConnection` you would use when you aren't referencing the generated proxy.  From the docs, `$.connection.hub` refers to the same object as `$.hubConnection()`

Comment: There is no "what's better" - it depends on the scenario. hubs is a dispatching mechanism built on top of persistent connection.