# Chat Realization with Singleton vs Separate SignalR Hub

Tags: signalr, blazor, blazor-server-side, signalr-hub

I was just wondering why [the recommended solution for a Blazor-Server-Chat by Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/azure/azure-signalr/signalr-tutorial-build-blazor-server-chat-app) is initializing a Signal R Hub.
Technically, all the C# Code is executed on the server, so it's also possible to realize the chat with a singleton:

```
public class MySingleton
{
    public event Action<string> OnBroadcast
    public void Send(string msg)
    {
        OnBroadcast.Invoke(msg);
    }
}
```

In the Blazor-Component I consume this singleton, subscribe to the event, and call `Send(...)`.

Why I should realize this Chat with a separate SignalR Hub?

Comment: This SO question might help: [Why choose Hub vs. Persistent Connection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9280484/signalr-why-choose-hub-vs-persistent-connection) and [How to get SignalR Hub Context](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27299289/how-to-get-signalr-hub-context-in-a-asp-net-core?rq=1) Apparently you should use IHubContext.

Comment: I guess it is just an academical example because it has no sense. Good point.

Comment: @Yogi But due to Blazor-Server I have a persistent connection anyway. So why initializing an additional hub.

Comment: The advantages of using a dedicated hub becomes clear when you  research it.  This Microsoft article outlines some of the advantages:  [Use hubs in SignalR](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/hubs?view=aspnetcore-6.0) Good question though as I'd not dug into this topic until now.

Comment: I notice that the sample is not a Blazor example, it is from the SignalR docs. So yes, it looks rather pointless. Unless when you were to scale-out your app to multiple servers.

Comment: I noticed using a dedicated Hub has also the advantage that it's easier to port the app to Blazor WebAssembly Application later

Answer (score 0):

In the document you linked, Microsoft isn't recommending you use a normal SignalR Hub for a chat application, they are providing documentation on how you can use Azure SignalR Service; a paid Azure service that simplifies using SignalR across multiple server instances. With a singleton you don't need a hub, but it won't work if your web app has multiple instances behind a load balancer.

If you only have one web app instance and you will never expand to additional instances, then the singleton approach would probably work fine.